# Why my HTML page is so small?

Tags: html, css

i cant see why this website registration page is so small. 
Im newbie to HTML.. Just want  to help with UX.

http://weelytics.com/app#register

Thank you!

Comment: Looks normal to me.  What do you mean by "so small"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try adding this to your css file.

```
body,html,#master {
   height:100%; 
}
.panel {
   margin-top:100px;
}
```